# How can call the jquery function onclick only parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a jQuery function when clicked only on parent element.

```
<div id="clcbox" class="click-img">
    <img id="fire" onclick="createFirework()" src="img/clicker.png" />
</div>
```

I have an `img` tag inside a `div`. When I click on the `div` it should call one function and when I click on the `img` I want to call another function. How can I do this?

```
$('.click-img, .wishes').click(function () {
    $('.flipWrapper').find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    return false;
});
```

When I click the `div` I should call the above function. However now when I click on the image, it is also calling this function and `createFirework()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to event bubbling. If you attach your events in an unobtrusive manner you can easily stop this behaviour.

```
<div id="clcbox" class="click-img">
    <img id="fire" src="img/clicker.png" />
</div>
```

```js
$('#fire').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    createFirework();
});

$('.click-img, .wishes').click(function (e) {
    $('.flipWrapper').find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't mix inline (`onclick`) event handlers and jQuery event handlers. Once, you've got a jQuery event handler in place of your `createFirework` method, you simply `stopPropagation` to stop it calling the handler on the outer div.

Below is an example

```js
$('.outer').click(function(e){
   alert("You clicked text in the div");  
});

$('.inner').click(function(e){
   alert("You clicked the button, but the div event handler will not fire");  
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <span>here is some text inside the div, click it</span>
  <button class="inner">Click me</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), to stop the click event bubble to its parents, but you also need to add a param event, so your function can access it without browser issue.

```
//                                     VVVV pass `event` as createFirework's param.
<img id="fire" onclick="createFirework(event)" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
```

But I'd suggest that answers that separate `js` part and `html` part would be better. Just like [Jamiec's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33496166/1737627).

```js
function createFirework(event) {
  console.log('inner');
  event.stopPropagation();
}

$('.click-img, .wishes').click(function () {
    console.log('outer');
    return false;
});
```

```css
#clcbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clcbox" class="click-img">
    <img id="fire" onclick="createFirework(event)" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Jamiec I passed in the event at markup, it seems to work on firefox. But I agree that js and markup should be separated, as your answer.

Comment: Ah yes, it does work like that. often people make the mistake of not passing `event` in from the markup - on IE & Chrome `event` is global and accessible without specifically passing it in.

Comment: I dont think you should delete it - its a good answer and may help someone in future.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, and always welcome for any comments that would correct my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use stopPropagation function:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp

In your case you need to add this on image click event:

```
$('.click-img, .wishes').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.flipWrapper').find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to stop the click event from the image bubbling up the DOM chain.

```
$('.click-img, .wishes').click(function (e) {
    $('.flipWrapper').find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

When you click on the image, that event is passed up to it's parent, in this case the `<div>`. That is by behavior. To stop that from ocurring, you call the [`stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) function that is part of the incoming event argument for the click event.